# Whose head is in Janeway's ready room?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, object-identification

On Star Trek: Voyager, Captain Janeway keeps a sculpture of a head on a shelf near her desk in her ready room.

[image]

[image]

Whose head is it?

Comment: Da Vinci maybe?

Comment: Obviously that's a bust of the creature in the center of the galaxy.  Voyager was originally planned to be given to it before it got lost in the delta quadrant.

Comment: I've added a better pic.

Comment: @ IG_42 I doubt it's Da Vinci, since she has his self portrait hanging in the same room (http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci).

Comment: Hammurabi? Nebuchadnezzar?

Comment: Can't find anything about that particular statue, but: http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=9448 Somebody DID buy schematics to her Ready Room. Maybe you can track them down and ask them?

Comment: I seem to recall it having been mentioned specifically somewhere. Maybe in *Counterpoint* or *Think Tank*?

Comment: and here I was thinking this question was about a shared toilet in the ready room

Comment: Are you asking whose bust this is supposed to be in the Star Trek universe or in reality (assuming its representative of someone famous in real history as opposed to who its supposed to be in the story) ??

Comment: @MikeMügge  It didn't occur to me that those would be different. I just assumed the producers had a particular person in mind and then got a sculpture of that person. I guess if they weren't the same, in universe, though both would be nice.

Comment: @AibaraIduas, I think its safe to say that the notion of buying a bust that matches a specific real life, classical period character for the set, would probably be overkill for a set designer.  It looks like they just purchased some random bust that would fit nicely with Janeway's character and made it part of the set.  Also, the only reference to it in a script that I can find occurs in season 5.  I highly doubt they would have included an accurate prop to the set initially, for a passing reference in a script 5 seasons later.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the bust might depict [Odysseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odysseus).

[image: statue of Odysseus]
<sup>(source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/69716881@N02/8559584513)</sup>

Probably the only time the bust is acknowledged on-screen is in [Voyager: Counterpoint](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/510.htm):

(Janeway and Inspector Kashyk are in her ready room. Kashyk is looking at Janeway's collection of artifacts and picks up the bust in question.)

> **KASHYK:** *It seems you have a long-standing obsession with exploration, Captain. I, on the other hand, have much more in common with **this ancient soldier**.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *He's from Earth's classical period. It produced some of our greatest artists as well.*

So he is referred to as a "soldier" as opposed to an "artist". I would say this description fits much better to Odysseus than to Aristotle or Archimedes.

Odysseus is often depicted bearded and wearing a [pileus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pileus_(hat)) (a kind of felt hat), so this also fits quite well.

Out of universe, I can totally see someone from the prop department putting in this little reference to Janeway's own Odyssey.

In universe it might be a bit harder to explain. We get the first glimpse of the bust in the very first episode, already in the Delta Quadrant but before Janeway could know that she herself will be on a long journey home.

Comment: Nice catch with the dialogue. It also resembles [this 'ancient greek warrior sculpture'](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ANCIENT-GREEK-WARRIOR-SCULPTURE-MUSEUM-REPRODUCTION-BUST-VINTAGE-STATUE-GREECE-/331915169192) sold on ebay--it's possible the prop department just found some similar anonymous classical-looking sculpture and thought it would work for a prop in Janeway's ready room without giving much thought to who it might be. There's a similar example that's not a reproduction [here](http://new.liveauctioneers.com/item/39596948_greek-bronze-warrior).

Comment: I think a starship captain might still identify with the exploratory spirit of Odysseus, which could explain why she had it.

Comment: @Adamant - Maybe in-universe, but I'm just not sure that in an out-of-universe sense the prop department would really have put that much thought into it. It looks pretty similar to [this knicknack](http://www.orlandistatuary.com/products/warrior-mask-on-pole?category=05&subcategory=0503) which as far as I can tell from google image searches is just a pseudo-ancient "greek warrior" rather than an actual reproduction of any ancient sculpture, so maybe they used something similar, or even an earlier edition of this one from the same makers.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Yeah, I meant in-universe.

Comment: Others seem to agree with this: http://www.trekbbs.com/threads/how-is-janeway-sexy-part-ii.151128/page-38

Comment: @MikeMügge - I see that thread also mentions an earlier thread called "Janeway's stuff" which I found at http://www.trekbbs.com/threads/janeways-stuff.139356/ , and on that thread someone mentions they found a copy of the dragon sculpture on ebay...I think that supports the idea that the prop department did just use a bunch of random knicknacks they found.

Comment: @Hypnosifl. I thought that was a given and that the OP's question is really who is it eluded to be in the Star Trek universe as opposed to real life. Perhaps we should ask OP for clarification on which answer he is seeking.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  That link you provided really does look almost identical. So they probably just used a generic prop.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, since it conforms with what little info given on the show. But it isn't ever explicitly stated, so I wonder if they producers even had an idea of who it was when they stuck it there. The prop itself is definitely just a generic head, as Hypnosifl points out above.

Comment: “In universe it might be a bit harder to explain. We get the first glimpse of the bust in the very first episode, already in the Delta Quadrant but before Janeway could know that she herself will be on a long journey home” — even exploring the Alpha Quadrant is still a long way from earth. I think the Odysseus comparison is still valid enough to Janeway to pick that bust pre-stranding.

Answer (score 18):

If you showed me this image out of the blue, without context, I would have thought it was [Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes).

[image]

[Compare](https://www.google.com/search?q=archimedes&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)

This fits with Janeway's backstory as a scientist on a philosophical and technical level.   In particular, an oft-quoted anecdote is the story him shouting [Eureka! Eureka!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(word)) on discovering the eponymously named principle of buoyancy.

Comment: I knew it looked familiar

Comment: Or Sophocles - http://static.newworldencyclopedia.org/thumb/4/49/Sophocles_bust.jpg/180px-Sophocles_bust.jpg

Comment: It looks like the sculpture in Janeway's room doesn't just have a band around its head, but is rather wearing some kind of helmet or hat which is a little larger and smoother than the upper part of the guy's head would be. More like [this](http://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/92/b3/16/92b3161280d78cac8a2b23c87284abe8.jpg) or [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Limestone_head_from_a_statue_of_a_worshipper_wearing_a_helmet_from_Idalion_at_the_British_Museum.jpg), for example.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yeah, it's clearly a smooth helmet of sorts, but those images you linked were clearly Greek (as was Valorum's suggestion). So it's almost certainly an ancient Greek someone or other, and Archimedes seems like an excellent guess.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Would Archimedes have been depicted wearing a helmet, though? My guess would be that those would be seen in sculptures of warriors or kings (or kingly gods like Zeus), not scholars or engineers (even engineers who, like Archimedes, designed some weapons of war).

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a sketch of Archimedes *with* a head garment on: http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/3afb68e9e2fb4cb2a5af0c88bddfab86/archimedes-circa-285-212-bc-greek-mathematician-portrait-engraving-ag1aj4.jpg

Comment: @Praxis - that doesn't appear to be a full head covering, just headband--I'm pretty sure that's a tuft of hair at the top of his head, not a hat tassle.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Wasn't sure what to call it, so I said "garment".  It's just thicker than the one in the answer.  I agree it's a hair tuft.

Answer (score 14):

I believe it's Aristotle.

[image]

Notably, Janeway's hero (Da Vinci) states that he looks up to Aristotle

> **JANEWAY:** *As a sparrow your mind would be too small? Even with the best of teachers?*
>
> **DA VINCI:** *If Aristotle himself were to perch on my branch and lecture till he fell off from exhaustion, still the limits of my mind
> would prevent me from understanding.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Voy: Concerning Flight](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/409.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: A page on that sculpture is [here](http://www.mfa.org/collections/object/bust-of-aristotle-58910), apparently it's a bust of Aristotle created in the 16th century, so maybe we coudl imagine Janeway wanted a bust of Aristotle of the type that Da Vinci might have owned, rather than one that looked more like how the ancient Greeks would have depicted him.

Comment: http://cache2.asset-cache.net/gc/128618119-bronze-bust-of-aristotle-aristotle-greek-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=J9LFbRM%2bAvW%2fKKqeopi%2fUw1z1weFNHB2fQqHjV4OS4HVQohBwRYmmkbovaWPyIPjUVVFI4hJobIkS55Mrgzr%2bg%3d%3d - There's a pic showing his funny little hat a bit better.

Comment: This one has the helmet, but not the curly beard. The Archimedes one has the curly beard, but not the helmet. I'm not sure what we're supposed to conclude, other than "some ancient philosopher".

Comment: @Martha I think it's fair to narrow it to "Some Ancient Greek philosopher."

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Well it's definitely not a famous depiction..

Comment: @Valorum  Not for us. Might could have been dug up sometime between now and 2370.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely Archimedes,  given Janeway's upbringing and career as a scientist before captain. The multitude of items Janeway keeps on her desk highlights her passion for the sciences. [image]

statue head of archimedes, a microscope, books, a geode, another microscope
A chinese dragon